# flink: Encryption parameters in flink-conf.yaml

Tags: apache-flink

Exist a way to encode parameters in flink-conf.yaml file?"
For example storing parameter like 'security.ssl.internal.keystore' in encrypted format.

Answer (score 0):

Flink currently does not support to encrypt configuration values. If this is required, then please create a JIRA issue with this feature request.

What Flink supports is to not display secrets in the web ui if their key contains `password` or `secret`. See [FLINK-14047](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14047) for more details.